# Need horizontal menu option on mouseover on a particular div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, menubar

My requirement is to make a horizontal menu in the end of a paragraph where on mouseover a menu should appear

[image: This is the paragraph where the menu is required at its end]

On mouse over it should show an option to add an item like this

[image]

On clicking the add option the menu should appear like this

[image]

Please suggest any jQuery or javascript plugin for this functionality. My preference is a plugin for this other than writing custom script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/cbARJ/4/

I don't have such background for your `Add here` buttons, so you will need to add it.

Comment: Thank you buddy for your quick response. Helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

EDIT: On mouse over for paragraph?

CSS:

```
p #add_link { display:none }
p:hover #add_link { display: block }
#links { display:none }
```

JS:

```
$('p #add_link').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().append($('#links').html()); // Or anything else
})
```